# Any other alternatives to displaying MySQL server data in android apart from Listview?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm learning android app development and recently learnt how to incorporate webservices into my app.I have searched for days over the internet and on this site as well,with absolutely no luck! I'm developing a simple quiz app,where questions are loaded from a remote MySQL database and currently they are being displayed in a List view,but the aim is to get each question and answer options on it's own separate activity ,such that the user selects an answer and presses a next button to move onto the next question etc.I could create the activities directly with each question  already,but the app needs to have that dynamic functionality where the questions could be altered from the server.I would really appreciate your help with ideas,maybe a tutorial or anything that will help me.Thank you.

Below is my edited code with viewpager from here < http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqFkkXMwWDg>

My AsyncTask class:

```
public class FetchQuestionsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> QuestionArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> AnswerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String msg;
    View description;

    public FetchQuestionsTask(Context context, View rootView) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.rootView = rootView;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (params == null)
            return null;

        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];

        try {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity == null) {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }

            // we get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg = "No Network Connection";
            Log.e("Log message", "No network connection");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {

        if (sJson == null) {

            return;
        }

        try {

            ArrayList<String> QuestionArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> AnswerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            // convert json string to json array
            JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);

                QuestionArray.add(json.getString("description"));
                // AnswerArray.add(json.getString("answer_text"));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            msg = "Invalid response";

        }

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(null, mContext);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            response string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

MyFragment class:

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Page1 extends Fragment {

    Context c2;
      String description, answer_text;

     /* public Page1() {
       }*/

      @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public Page1(Context c2,String description,String answer_text){
          this.c2 = c2;
            this.description = description;
            this.answer_text = answer_text;  
      }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages_list,container, false);

        c2=getActivity();
        new FetchQuestionsTask(c2, v).execute("http://10.0.2.2/webservice/new_questions");


        try{

            TextView question_txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.q_description);
            question_txt.setText(description);

            TextView answer_txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ans_txt);
            answer_txt.setText(answer_text);        
        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("Log error :", "could not write the text views");

        }
                return v;
    }



}
```

My adapter class:

```
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> QuestionArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>AnswerArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    private int []colors = {Color.parseColor("#00B050"),Color.parseColor("#FFC000"), Color.parseColor("#DB1351"),
            Color.parseColor("#B61C83"), Color.parseColor("#0070C0")};
    Context c;
    private Random rnd;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context c) {
        super(fm);
        this.c = c;}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String description = QuestionArray.get(position);
        String answer_text = AnswerArray.get(position);

        fragment = new Page1(c, description, answer_text);//pass value to be displayed in inflated view
         return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return QuestionArray.size(); //get number of pages to be displayed
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use viewpager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html ...

Comment: Hi Shruti..thank you so much for your response.I've read about the viewpager and it's something i'll definitely look into.My greatest challenge right now however is that,how do i move from that list view display of questions,to that level of using the viewpager?

Comment: the ListView have an adapter, the pager have an adapter as well (they're different types of adapters, but have similar concept), so it's just some moving around. Try to forget your app now and do a simple ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter, just to understand how they work,

Comment: Thanks Budius. I'm gonna read up on it and let you know tomorrow the kind of progress I've made.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: gr8 ... I think you have got you confusion cleared from Budius.

Comment: yes..thank you both so much for steering me in the right direction.I managed to get lots of info about viewpager and i have a sample implementation just from reading about it yesterday from a tutorial.Unfortunately,the app does not show any data from the database.I will post my code below.Kindly have a look at my code and let me know my mistakes..

Comment: @Budius i just edited my question..it now has the code i've tried.Please help..

Comment: I'm at work and really can't be debugging each line of code. But as a general suggestions: Activity->AsyncTask->onPostExecute you create the adapter with the correct data inside it. Also, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), Google them, they're simpler and more flexible then the base PagerAdapter

Comment: Hi @Shruti.thank you so much for the links and the support.those links really opened my eyes.I know that i definitely need to use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter because of memory.So according to my posted code above,currently i can just display the views or pages,without any data from my mysql db.Could you kindly show me how to implement a FragmentStatePagerAdapter in the OnPostExecute method of async task?All the examples i have found with this adapter,do not deal with downloading JSON data asynchronously.Or a tutorial that uses asyncTask,viewpager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [viewpager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). It will perfectly solve your problem.

and here is the link for [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

If still you have problem understanding it have a look on the example from this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/)

Here is one more link which shows comparison of [Android FragmentPagerAdapter vs FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-fragmentpageradapter-vs-fragmentstatepageradapter/)

Take a look you will get to know the differences.

Comment: Hey Shruti,i followed your advice,implemented the FragmentStatePagerAdapter but now i'm getting a null pointer exception in the OnPostExecute in AsyncTask class

Comment: put that try...catch block inside your if condition

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction.I followed your advice and had to do a lot more,but eventually got it working!Thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: that's cool ... if it worked for you then simply accept the answer :)

Comment: there you go..i just did :)